# How to get fields from ExecuteAsync() method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, google-drive-api, async-await

I'm familiar with creating folder in my Google Drive, but I'm looking into doing this using the asynchronous method. However, in doing so, I'm not sure how to obtain a field that I explicitly added to the fields I'd like returned.

My code below:

```
private Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> CreateGoogleDriveFolderAsync(DriveService service, string foldername, string parent_id = null)
{
    IList<string> parent_ids = new List<string>();

    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File folder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
    {
        Name = foldername
        , MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
        , Description = "Client Name: blah\nUser: Rudy\n"
    };

    var insert = service.Files.Create(folder);

    // The field I'd like to get somewhere.
    insert.Fields = "id";

    var task = insert.ExecuteAsync();

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // NotOnRanToCompletion - this code will be called if the upload fails
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to create folder \"{0}\": " + t.Exception, foldername);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // I'd like a way to access "id" from my insert execution.
        log.insertLogging(foldername, "Directory Created");
    });

    return task;
}
```

Comment: await the task and get the file back from there you should have access to its properties

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi , I am awaiting, but access to "its" properties? My method call is as follows: `await CreateGoogleDriveFolderAsync(service, "MyNewFolder");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder), `await` the task and get the file back from there you should have access to its properties

```
private async Task<File> CreateGoogleDriveFolderAsync(DriveService driveService, string foldername) {
    var metadata = new File()
    {
        Name = foldername,
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    };
    var request = driveService.Files.Create(metadata);
    request.Fields = "id";
    var folder = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Folder ID: " + folder.Id);

    return folder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I wasn't setting the await call to anything. I also found that in the method I could do this: `task.Result.Id`, where `task.Result` returns the Google File. Thanks again.